# MATLAB problems

Tags: matlab

1st m-file

```
clear pH Fb
pH = 5:0.1:9;
for i = 1:length(pH)
    Fb(i) = pH2Fb(pH(i));
end 
plot(Fb,pH)
```

2nd m-file

```
function Fb=pH2Fb(pH)   
Fb=fsolve(@fun1,1,[],pH);

function f=fun1(Fb,pH)  

 Fa = 2.9; %ml/s
 Ca = 3e-3; %mol/ml
 Cb = 5e-5; %mol/ml
 Ca1 = -3e-3; %mol/ml
 pk1 = 1.27;
 pk2 = 4.266;    
 Xa = (Fa*Ca+Fb*Ca1)/(Fa+Fb);  
 Xb = (Fb*Cb)/(Fa+Fb); 
 f= (Xa + 10^(pH-14)-10^(-pH)+ Xb*(1+2*10^(pH-pk2))/(1+10^(pk1-pH)+10^(pH-pk2)))*1e19;
```

here's the questions:

1.
   for `Fb=fsolve(@fun1,1,[ ],pH);`
   what it meant by the equation above??

2.
   for 2nd m-file, why `"function f=fun1(Fb,pH)"` is stated after `"Fb=fsolve(@fun1,1,[ ],pH);"`

meanwhile the function "fun1" is called at before it is being solve?? because so far
   that I know, MATLAB is run is from upper to bottom and supposely the "fun1" is
   undefined as it being solve later..

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your two questions:

1. The call to `fsolve` is using an [old MATLAB syntax](http://infoshako.sk.tsukuba.ac.jp/ShakoDoc/MATLAB5/help/toolbox/optim/fsolve.html) for passing an argument to the objective function. The call is optimizing for the objective function `@(x) fun1(x, pH)` starting from the initial value `1` and passing no options (`[]`). For recent versions of MATLAB this should be written

   `fsolve(@(x) fun1(x, pH), 1)`
2. `fun1` is a [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-39683.html) so can be called from within it's parent function `pH2Fb`.